# Type Mismatch while trying to make code faster

Tags: excel, vba

I was trying to change over to the For Loop (For i = 1 To UBound(arrSOPID,1) to make the code faster; before I was looping through a lot of cells according to some advice I received.

Then I get a type mismatch on this part...Trim(arrSOPID(i, 1)

```
   'Store cells in COL A that have values as a range
    Dim arrSOPID As Variant: Set arrSOPID = .Range("A1", .Range("A1").End(xlDown))
    Dim cel As Range

    'Loop through each SOP audit file
    For Each oFile In oFiles
        'Strip audit date out of filename and trim off the file extension
        Dim auditDate As Date: auditDate = CDate(DateSerial(Right(Left(Split(oFile.Name, "-")(3), 8), 4), _
                                                    Left(Left(Split(oFile.Name, "-")(3), 8), 2), _
                                                    Mid(Left(Split(oFile.Name, "-")(3), 8), 3, 2)))
        Dim i As Long: i = 0
        'Loop through all SOP IDs stored in COL A
        For i = 1 To UBound(arrSOPID, 1)
            'MsgBox (Trim(arrSOPID(i, 1)))
            'See if SOP ID in COL A matches SOP ID in Audit file name
            If Trim(RemoveLeadingZeroes(Split(oFile.Name, "-")(2))) = Trim(arrSOPID(i, 1)) Then
                'Insert link to audit, change background color, etc of selected cell
                With cel.Offset(0, 3 + Month(auditDate))
                    .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=cel.Offset(0, 3 + Month(auditDate)), Address:=oFile.Path, TextToDisplay:="X"
                    .Interior.Color = RGB(34, 139, 34)
                    .Font.Color = vbBlack
                    .Font.Bold = True
                End With
            End If
        Next i
    Next oFile
```

Comment: Perhaps `arrSOPID(i, 1)` isn't a string?

Comment: Its a set of numbers in COL A...arrSOPID is populating though. It just has a problem with arrSOPID(i, 1)

Comment: Try `Debug.Print` the value each time through - see what it prints last before it throws

Comment: It gives me the same error on the Debug.Print line.

Comment: Your array is of type `Variant`. You need to store your array variable in a `String` variable before using `Trim()`.

Comment: `Set arrSOPID = .Range("A1", .Range("A1").End(xlDown))` assigns `arrSOPID` as a `Variant/Range`.  I think you mean `arrSOPID = .Range("A1", .Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array is of type `Variant`. You need to store your array variable in a `String` variable BEFORE you use the `Trim()`. Something like below should work:

```vb
'Store cells in COL A that have values as a range
    Dim arrSOPID As Variant: Set arrSOPID = .Range("A1", .Range("A1").End(xlDown))
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim myStr as String

    'Loop through each SOP audit file
    For Each oFile In oFiles
        'Strip audit date out of filename and trim off the file extension
        Dim auditDate As Date: auditDate = CDate(DateSerial(Right(Left(Split(oFile.Name, "-")(3), 8), 4), _
                                                    Left(Left(Split(oFile.Name, "-")(3), 8), 2), _
                                                    Mid(Left(Split(oFile.Name, "-")(3), 8), 3, 2)))
        Dim i As Long: i = 0
        'Loop through all SOP IDs stored in COL A
        For i = 1 To UBound(arrSOPID, 1)
            myStr = arrSOPID(i, 1)
            'MsgBox (Trim(myStr))
            'See if SOP ID in COL A matches SOP ID in Audit file name
            If Trim(RemoveLeadingZeroes(Split(oFile.Name, "-")(2))) = Trim(myStr) Then
                'Insert link to audit, change background color, etc of selected cell
                With cel.Offset(0, 3 + Month(auditDate))
                    .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=cel.Offset(0, 3 + Month(auditDate)), Address:=oFile.Path, TextToDisplay:="X"
                    .Interior.Color = RGB(34, 139, 34)
                    .Font.Color = vbBlack
                    .Font.Bold = True
                End With
            End If
        Next i
    Next oFile
```

Comment: Same type mismatch on myStr = arrSOPID(i, 1)

Comment: What is the data type in your range? Are you trying to use `Trim()` on numbers?

Comment: @mongoose00318 Please read here for more information on the `Trim()` function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ltrim-rtrim-and-trim-functions

Answer (score 0):

Can you try Trim(Cstring(arrSOPID(i, 1))) ?